# Invoke-WebRequest, POST Method Formatting Issue

Tags: powershell, api, post

I'm trying to create a script to make some Post requests to an API I need to work with and am having some issues understanding how to make this work with PowerShell. I started by playing around with the API in postman and in that my requests work but I think I'm missing something in how to format this for PowerShell:

Here is my PowerShell:

```
    $body = @{
        "jsonrpc"="2.0'"
        "method"="Login"
         }
          "partner"="<string>"
          "username"="<email>"
          "password"="<password>"
         }
          "id"="1"
         }
$contentType = "application/json"
Invoke-WebRequest -Method POST -Uri "<URL>" -body $body -ContentType $contentType
```

Here is what the body looks like in Postman, this is just to get my API token:

```
    {
    "jsonrpc":"2.0",
    "method":"Login",
    "params":{
        "partner":"<string>",
        "username":"<email>",
        "password":"<password>"
    },
    "id":"1"
}
```

I'm looking for both links to learn how to work with a POST method API and some pointers on how to get this first request to work, from here I should be able to play around with it and get to my goal.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess, looks like the solarwinds api, anyway...
your json structure is not valid...

You can construct it like this:

```
$params = @{
jsonrpc = '2.0';
method = 'Login'
    params = @{
    username = "email"
    password = "password"
    }
id = "1"
} | ConvertTo-Json

$Token = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Body $params -Method Post
```

the final body should looks like this:

```
{
    "method":  "Login",
    "params":  {
                   "password":  "password",
                   "username":  "email"
               },
    "id":  "1",
    "jsonrpc":  "2.0"
}
```

Comment: Yes this is the Solarwinds API, thank you I'll give this a try.

Comment: This is working now but I wonder if you know how I can output the visa without changing the formatting? I tried Select-Object -ExpandProperty visa and $visa.visa but I can't seem to use this in subsequent API calls due to the formatting being malformed.

Comment: using my example just do: `$Token.visa`